# What does this 'metaclass' method do?

Tags: ruby

```
def metaclass; class << self; self; end; end
```

Can someone decipher this line for me. I guess the fact that it's squeezed into one doesn't help much either. But having started looking at ruby only 2 days ago, I fear I might break it apart incorrectly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Breaking it apart:

```
def metaclass
  class << self
    self
  end
end
```

Note that this is available as a built-in method in Ruby 1.9.2 (`Object#singleton_class`).

What this does is returning the singleton_class/metaclass/eigenclass of an object by opening the same via `class << self` and then returning it (`self`). If you are confused about metaclasses per se, I'd recommend the following article:

[The Ruby Object Model - Structure and Semantics](http://www.hokstad.com/ruby-object-model.html)

Comment: It's strange that a semicolon is not required after the method name `metaclass` in OPs original.

Comment: @sawa What do you mean? `irb> def metaclass class << self; self; end; end #=> SyntaxError: (irb):1: syntax error, unexpected keyword_class, expecting ';' or '\n'`

Comment: @Phrogz Thats' exactly what I mean. The question was like that, and was edited 7 minutes before your comment.